# Java exec and rundll32 parameter issue

Tags: exec

I'm having a strange issue launching Windows Photo Viewer from Java with the String[] exec (actually I'm using Commons Exec but internally it goes there)

```
    String exec = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\rundll32.exe \"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen c:\\temp\\foo.png";   
String[] params = new String[] {"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\rundll32.exe", "\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen", "c:\\temp\\foo.png"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exec);
int result = process.waitFor();
System.out.println(result);
```

If I run this, the program spawns just fine but if I try exec(params) I just return immediately with 0.

I assume the problem is somewhere around the "quoted dll", operation section but I haven't been able to pinpoint it. Pointers?

Thanks in advance,
 Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be some quotes wrong:

The path to the dll can be set without the additional quotes. Also the ImageView_Fullscreen can be supplied as separate parameter

```
String[] params = new String[] {"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\rundll32.exe", "C:\\Program Files\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll", "ImageView_Fullscreen", "c:\\temp\\foo.png"};
```

This should open the file.

Comment: Hey, cool! I was thrown off a bit since most command line examples actually include the "," after the dll but it appears to work without it, too